# SELECT one row of a table, And all rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

if i have these two tables:

```
[    id    -     title    -     content    ]
[    1    -     title1    -     content1   ]
[    2    -     title2    -     content2   ]
```

and

```
[    id    -     pid    -       tags   ]
[    1    -       1    -        TAG1   ]
[    2    -       1    -        TAG2   ]
[    3    -       1    -        TAG3   ]
[    4    -       2    -        TAG2   ]
```

Now what i'm trying to do is Select the `title` and `content` from `table1` then all `tags` from `table2` where `b.pid = a.id`

so my query is

```
SELECT a.title, a.content, b.tags
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.pid
WHERE a.id = 1
```

What i want to get is

`title1
content1
TAG1 TAG2 TAG3`

but what i get is only `TAG1` and repeated values of `title1 content1` for each tag

Then i tried

```
SELECT a.title, a.content, 
 (SELECT DISTINCT b.tags)
  FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
  WHERE a.id = 1
```

but still don't work as intended.

Comment: You have two _tables_, not _databases_.

Comment: @jarlh i "fixed" that while changing code lines to blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ibtain the tags related to id on the same row you could use group_concat

```
  select  a.title, a.content, group_concat(b.tags)
  from table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.pid
  WHERE a.id = 1
  group by  a.title, a.content
```

you can use count on the same  query too

```
  select  a.title, a.content, group_concat(b.tags), count(*)
  from table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.pid
  WHERE a.id = 1
  group by  a.title, a.content
```

for distinct tas you can use

```
 select  a.title, a.content, group_concat(distinct b.tags)
  from table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.pid
  WHERE a.id = 1
  group by  a.title, a.content
```

Comment: in case i want to use `COUNT()` for all the tags, Does it have the same trait?

Comment: answer  updated ..but adding request step by step is not fair  ..once and answer  is crrectly solved you should accept  teh answer  and eventaally post a new well documented  question

Comment: be aware that the length of group_concat defaults to 1024 characters, if you have many tags your string will be truncated

Comment: was waiting for the 6min to accept answer, sorry about that.